# Regular expression for parsing complex CSV having parentheses

Tags: .net, regex, parsing, csv

I need to parse a csv like this -

`[{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}]`

I just need the data between () and then parse it again to get actual values.

I am able to fetch (a,b,c) | (d,e,f) etc. using this regEx - `{[^}]*?}`

How can I get just a,b,c and d,e,f as groups?

Comment: What do you mean by `get (...) a,b,c and d,e,f as groups`?

Comment: did I answer you, or can I help you with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `look-ahead` and `look-behind` in the `regex` like this `(?<={)[^}]*?(?=})`
this will get you only `a,b,c` type values in groups

Comment: @user1041579 pls accept the answer if it helped you. it helps everybody on the network.

Answer (score 0):

```
{([^}]*?)}
```

then you can get  `a,b,c` with m.Groups[1]